# use strict error use the function form of "use strict"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I add `use strict` on the following code I get this error, why?

> L1:C1] W097: Use the function form of "use strict". 'use strict';
>   [L3:C1] W117: 'angular' is not defined. angular.module('app.login',
>   [ [L30:C9] W117: 'console' is not defined.
>           console.log(resources); [L34:C13] W117: 'console' is not defined.
>               console.log("clicked!");
>
> Warning: Task "jshint:src" failed. Use --force to continue.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.login', [
        'ui.router',
    ])

    .config(function config($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            views: {
                "main": {
                    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'login/login.tpl.html'
                }
            },
            data: {}
        });
    })

    .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope','resources', function ($scope, resources) {

        $scope.user = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };      

    }]);
```

If I understand correctly it wants me to use a wrapper i.e. `(function() {` but I don't understand why this would be required!

Comment: 'use strict' should be first expression in function, to make this error go away just wrap the whole thing in IIFE.

Comment: @jcubic `"use strict"` may also appear at the global scope level